# Form approval workflow help required

Tags: workflow, form

We have developed an infopath form that we use in our team for doing our daily IT backup checks.

We do this first thing in the morning and usually have to update the form later in the day as there are some backups that are running later into the morning.

Obviously we would like to save the form as we're going along incase web browser crashes as lots of data to fill out.

Once its complete we want a form approval process to go to manager to check form and then approve it - he selects his name and enters the date - now I dont know if theres a way for it to show that he approved it without having to select his name? - Can this be done based on Active Directory logon?

We have tried doing the approval process before and when you hit submit the approval process works however if you want to edit the form again later once the other backups have finished then this process starts again - we dont want duplicate files appearing in the sharepoint list.

Any asstiance with this would be helpful.

Cheers.

Comment: Before starting the approval process you can check if Current Item's approval status. If its not approved then only start the approval process.

Comment: Could you re-word this, I dont quite understand your reply.

Comment: In Workflow you can add conditions. So add a condition which check the whether the form is approved or not. Inside the condition you can start the approval activity.